# How can I replace a function? Something like f[x] /. f -> -g. ReplaceAll doesnt seem to work properly when there is a minus sign

Tags: replacement

How can I replace a function with minus another function?
This: 
 `Sin[x] /. Sin -> Cos`
works just fine.
But this: 
 `Sin[x] /. Sin -> -Cos`
gives 
 `(-Cos)[x]`
and I cannot evaluate it, in this output x is not recongnized as the function's argument.
Seems simple but I could not find a way to do this. Help, please!

Comment: `Sin[x] /. Sin[aa_]:>-Cos[aa]` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Sin[x] /. Sin[x] -> -Cos[x]
```

which gives you `-Cos[x]`

If you have a slightly more complicated problem like `Sin[x] + Sin[y]` and you want to replace both those `Sin` then this

```
Sin[x] + Sin[y] /. Sin[z_] :> -Cos[z]
```

will give you `-Cos[x] - Cos[y]`

Comment: The second expression worked perfectly to solve my problem. Thank you, Bill!

Comment: It is best to use RuleDelayed for named pattern replacements unless you specifically know you need otherwise.  I edited your answer accordingly.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Bill, and what about `Sin[x]+Sin[f[x]]`

Comment: @dtn `Sin[x]+Sin[f[x]]/.Sin[u_]->Cos[u]` returns `Cos[x]+Cos[f[x]]` but I don't know how to test that in your situation to tell whether it is working for you or not. Does that work for you? If not then can you provide something that I can use to test this?

Answer (score 4):

I usually replace the `f` with a pure function this way:

```
Sin[x] /. Sin -> (-Cos[#] &)
```

It substitutes for all `f`, if there is more than one form of `f` in the expression

```
Sin[x] + Sin[x^2]/. Sin -> (-Cos[#] &)
(*  -Cos[x] - Cos[x^2]  *)
```

The same approach works if there are pure derivatives in the expression, such as when using a known solution to factor and reduce the order of a linear ODE (in the example below, $y= x$ is a solution, so factor $y = x \int u \,dx$ to get a first-order equation for $u$):

```
y''[x] + x^2 y'[x] - x y[x] == 0 /. {y -> (# Integrate[u[#], #] &)} // Simplify
(*  (2 + x^3) u[x] + x u'[x] == 0  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works :

```
Sin[x] /. Sin[xx_] -> -Cos[xx]
```

> -Cos[x]

It is safer to use (if x is allready defined) :

```
Sin[x] /. Sin[xx_] :> -Cos[xx]
```

The following seems to work too :

```
Sin[x] /. Sin -> Composition[Minus,Cos]
```

though I have never used this latest form.

Comment: any advice from anybody about the latest form ?

Comment: I think the Composition version (shorthand is Minus @* Cos) is good.

Comment: The form with `Composition` certainly works if `x` is just a symbol (and you can use the shortcut version: `Sin[x] /. Sin -> Minus@*Cos`), so that `Sin[x]` remains unevaluated before the replacement is done. However, if *x* has a numeric value, as in `Sin[Pi/2]`, then it won't work, because `Sin[Pi/2]` will be evaluated to give `1` and then there's nothing left in which to replace `Sin` by anything!

Comment: @murray: isn't that a general problem with all of these replacement rules? If `Sin[arg]` evaluates to an exact value on the left side of `/.`, none of the above answers will work because none of the replacement rules will ever see the `Sin` function. The only way to handle this problem, is by using some form of holding.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: Yes, precisely the problem!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to force *Mathematica* handle head operations of this kind as follows:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];

Unprotect[Times];

(-h_?NumericFunctionQ)[arg__] := -h[arg];

Protect[Times];
```

Now:

```
Sin[x] /. Sin -> -Cos
```

> ```
> -Cos[x]
> ```

Standard caveats of modifying built-ins apply.

Comment: I think this suffers from serious IC (inadequate caveatation). I'll bet you didn't even know that disease existed...

Comment: @Daniel lol -- yup, that's new to me.  I expect a performance hit, perhaps serious, but I didn't think of anything this would break outright.  Can you enlighten me?

Comment: Anything that messes with `Plus`, `Times`, or `Power` is potentially problematic, insofar as much of the internal uses do not go through top-level code (for reasons of efficiency) and hence might give results other than expected.

Comment: @Daniel Is that true even for *symbolic* evaluations such as this?  I am aware that packed arrays bypass top level definitions, but I didn't anticipate that here.

Comment: There is a considerable amount of usage of those functions in internal code, even in the absence of packed arrays. So yes. Also, unprotecting and changing those functions can hasten the End of Days. Did I neglect to mention that? Silly of me.